# Get r,g,b pixel from an image

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

I am new at image processing and I use emgu cv with c# and I have a problem.
How can I get R,G,B pixel value from RGB value from an image?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Not certain, but it looks like there's a `Data` property that you can use to access the pixels directly. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/15045295/56778

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you need to get the RGB values:

```
//load image
Image<Bgr, byte> image = new Image<Bgr, byte>("sample.png");

//get the pixel from [row,col] = 24,24
Bgr pixel = image[24, 24];

//get the b,g,r values
double b = pixel.Blue;
double g = pixel.Green;
double r = pixel.Red;
```

Comment: Where did the `frame1` come from?

Comment: +1 whats the type Bgr? and why doubles they should be `int`s?

Comment: @JeremyThompson the properties Blue, Green, and Red are of type double

Comment: I dont know what the type `Bgr` is... but in general R G B are `ints` http://stackoverflow.com/a/14950437/495455

Comment: @JeremyThompson Bgr is a type struct with properties, Red, Green and Blue whose types are double (see http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/html/c1baae67-dbe8-3c62-98e9-d4e988307eba.htm) for more information

Comment: for YCbCr channel what can I do?

Comment: to get the YCbCr pixels, convert the image to YcbCr color space: Ycc ycrcb = image.Convert<Ycc,byte>(), then you get the pixels as before.